# Is it possible to create a Gmail filter that works on headers other than From, To, Subject?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I've forwarded one of my really old email addresses to Gmail.  I'd like to create a filter so that any mail to that old address is always labeled properly in Gmail.

I can create a Gmail filter with the "To: " containing that address, but that doesn't catch *all* mails to that address, only the ones that are explicitly addressed.  Often, there is spam where somebody else is the explicit recipient, and my old address was simply Bcc'd.  The "To: " filter doesn't work.

What I'd *like* to do is filter on the "Delivered-To:" header.  Is that possible with Gmail or am I stuck with the three standard options of From, To, Subject?

Comment: Related: [Create a Gmail filter for Calendar Notifications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60188/21843)

Comment: The title question fails to accord with the body question, Chris, how about fixing the title question to avoid wasting the time of readers arriving here by search?

Comment: @ChrisJJ What would you suggest?

Answer (score 96):

Yes, you can filter by "Delivered-To". Just create a new filter with `deliveredto:youremail@address.com` in the `has the words` field.

Note that the "has" filter name doesn't have "-" in its name as opposed to the original email header name.

Comment: Not very intuitive, but yes. I think most `to:` should be `deliveredto:` actually, to support BCCs.

Comment: Has this worked with wildcards too, for example, using a _catch-all email_ address in `deliveredto:*@mydomain.com`?  I am trying it but will take time to test.

Comment: It seems to work for me. I never thought it wouldn't, so I haven't tested it exhaustively, but I haven't noticed any missing messages in the 3+ years that I've been using such filters.

Comment: Marcos, I replied to your question you posted. Try adding quotes around the "@domain.com" in your search.

Comment: Note that you can use the search bar at the top of GMail to construct your advanced search, then click the arrow at the end of the search bar and select "Create filter with this search."

Comment: works as advertised, but my sent messages have this header set to my address :(

Comment: This does not solve the problem for headers other than Delivered-To? (Say a search for the Auto-submitted or Precedence headers)

Comment: It's pretty obnoxious that the header text is "Delivered-To:" while the "has" field eliminates the '-' to yield "deliveredto:".

Comment: @JamesBowery Yes, Google isn't exactly known for quality UI or UX.

Comment: I had the issue that the `Delivered-To` header was *not* exactly the email that my mail was being delivered to – my email was something like `me@example.com`, but the header was `Delivered-To: me@mailrelay.example.com`.  Once I used the latter, it worked perfectly.

Comment: This does not work anymore, I tried a few variants too.

Comment: @BenjaminGoodacre it's still working for me now - you might want to verify that you've got the correct header in your messages ([Show original](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436?hl=en) function).

Answer (score 58):

1. go to https://script.google.com and create a new Google Apps Script

[image: new google apps script.]

1. select the "Create script for Gmail" option

   - this will create a script project
   - this will create a script called `Code.gs`
   - this will create sample functions, one them named `processInbox`
2. save the project
3. customize the script and test it until you are satisfied
4. find the "custom project's triggers" button

   [image: custom trigger button]

   - this will let you run the script on a timer (e.g. daily, or **every minute**)

## Example:

### processInbox

This function will iterate over all messages in the Inbox.

```
function processInbox() {
   // process all recent threads in the Inbox (see comment to this answer)
   var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1h");
   for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      // get all messages in a given thread
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
         var message = messages[j];
         processMessage(message);
      }
   }
}
```

Go one step further and call [`GmailApp.search()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)) if you want to do something fancy instead of `GmailApp.getInboxThreads()`.

### processMessage

This function will take care of processing a single message; you get the raw content with `getRawContent()` and try to find your header in there, if it is in there, tag the message.

```
function processMessage(message) {
  var body = message.getRawContent();
  if (body.indexOf("X-Custom-Header: some-custom-value") > -1) {
    // do stuff with message (e.g. add label)
  }
}
```

Comment: My unproven gut reaction is that google will have something in place to stop users looping through gigs worth of raw email content every minute.  So I'd advise to replace " var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();" with " var threads = GmailApp.search("newer_than:1h");"

Comment: I am using `var MyEmails = GmailApp.search("is:unread in:inbox");` in order to search all email in the inbox which are not yet read

Comment: @Rick - I wrote a script that uses the IMAP interface to walk through all 13+GB in my gmail account.  'Wouldn't surprise me if script.google.com allowed it.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone coming to this like I was trying to do exactly this, you can't add a label to a message, only to the thread, so you'll need to do `message.getThread().addLabel(GMailApp.getUserLabelByName("Some Label"))`

Comment: You can get header of the message, that could be better than searching through the body, especially for messages with attachments.

Comment: How could I auto-search for new incoming messages/threads whose `return-path` header field contains "`gorkanadatabase`" and then apply a label? `Return-Path: <sprbounce+B32$VZZJFLTLTBY3GN4Q5JHXJIPJSI======@gorkanadatabase.com>`

Comment: Very impressive! But why `message.getRawContent()` and `body.indexOf("X-Custom-Header: some-custom-value")` and not just `message.getHeader()` and `body == "X-Custom-Header: some-custom-value"`? If agreed, please modify the answer.

Answer (score 52):

Here is a list of all the advanced operators:

> from:
>   to:
>   subject:
>   OR
>   - (hyphen)
>   label:
>   has:attachment
>   list:
>   filename:
>   " " (quotes)
>   ( )
>   in:anywhere
>   in:inbox
>   in:trash
>   in:spam
>   is:important
>   is:starred
>   is:unread
>   is:read
>   has:yellow-star
>   has:red-star
>   has:orange-star
>   has:green-star
>   has:blue-star
>   has:purple-star
>   has:red-bang
>   has:orange-guillemet
>   has:yellow-bang
>   has:green-check
>   has:blue-info
>   has:purple-question
>   cc:
>   bcc:
>   after:
>   before:
>   older:
>   newer:
>   older_than:
>   newer_than:
>   is:chat
>   deliveredto:
>   circle:
>   has:circle
>   category:
>   size:
>   larger:
>   smaller:
>   + (plus sign)
>   rfc822msgid:
>   has:userlabels
>   has:nouserlabels

[[source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)]

Comment: Thanks. Even their pages make it difficult to determine if a NOT operator `-` would work on wildcard addresses, eg: `-*@mydomain.com` in the `To:` field

Comment: Google gives me `Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g. "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming emails. Do you still wish to continue to the next step?` - is `is:` actually a viable filter in some way?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `deliveredto:` operator in the `Has the words` field when creating a filter, as @mvime indicated. However, not all email providers append `Delivered-to` to the email header, so a more reliable way is to forward `you@oldemail.com` to `you+oldemail@gmail.com`, and filter by `deliveredto:(you+oldemail@gmail.com)`.