# Is it possible to create a Gmail filter that works on arbitrary headers?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-headers

(Not a dup: [this very similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/is-it-possible-to-create-a-gmail-filter-that-works-on-headers-other-than-from-to) really asks about the `DeliveredTo` header).

Bugzilla provides a number of headers telling you why you received a mail, such as `X-Bugzilla-Reason`. How can I filter on arbitrary tags such as this one in Gmail?

Comment: I'm offering a bounty; I really need this. (Bugzilla is my use case, too.)

Comment: I want this for paypal's email-xclick-payment-notification header, delivered in the header X-MaxCode-Template.  Sigh.

Comment: @dnozay appears to have answered this in the following post in a similar topic: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/73544/97407 I have not verified if it works, and it does involve writing some code. But if it works, it should help this situation.

Comment: GitLab notifications also have such headers.

How is it possible that one of the most used email clients doesn't offer filtering beyond the absolutely basic functionality. It's frustrating when you know it can't possible be much work to implement either when the basic filter mechanism already exists..

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Q-A/Filtering-words-in-email-headers/m-p/511648/highlight/true#M9313

Answer (score 8):

Gmail doesn't do this. But if the emails do have text in the message, it can do it.

Comment: Bugzilla only adds custom headers; it doesn't modify the body of the message. :-(

Comment: Sad. I'd love to be able to do this. Looks like I'd need a bot.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @[Andrew](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/43/andrew) - Gmail won't handle this on its own.

However, you could use an intermediary running `procmail`<sup>[1](http://www.procmail.org)</sup>, preprocess the mail and add something to the subject, or change its sender, so that it can be filtered secondarily in Gmail.