# How do I filter PayPal emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a donation button on my website.  Donation emails from PayPal are marked "From:" the person who donated.

How can I create a filter in Gmail to filter these emails into a label?  (I'd do it by subject, but there are a variety of subjects, so I'm afraid I'll miss one.)

Comment: Possibly related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/is-it-possible-to-create-a-gmail-filter-that-works-on-headers-other-than-from-to

Answer (score 2):

All the donation I received through PayPal in the past were using the subjet

```
Notification of donation received
```

Couldn't you use it? Otherwise, you can use the `Has the words` filter and put the words `paypal donation`. It's not a bullet proof filter, but it should work in most of the cases.