# How to filter by a catch-all address in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Does anyone fathom how to setup a Gmail/Google Apps Mail filter that catches ALL destinations to a particular domain?

I've tried

```
deliveredto:*@mydomain.com
```

and

```
deliveredto:@mydomain.com
```

in the "Has the words" field but neither work.

Similar to this question except not specific to any complete address (only the domain is constant in my case, the user/account part before the @ is unpredictable):
[Is it possible to create a Gmail filter that works on headers other than From, To, Subject?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/is-it-possible-to-create-a-gmail-filter-that-works-on-headers-other-than-from-t)

I already have another filter setup to catch and forward `*@mydomain.com` *in the **To:** field*; that works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`deliveredto:"@mydomain.com"`

Not sure why this works when the others don’t, but the quotes act as some kind of delimiter.

Comment: Haven't tried it but thanks. [Parens](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26031/15698) worked for me.

Comment: Its not longer working in 2023 sadly

Answer (score 2):

Using parens seems to do the trick:

```
deliveredto:(*@mydomain.com)
```

Also figured out how to negate properly (placement of hyphen):

```
-to:(*@mydomain.com)
```

Combined:

```
deliveredto:(*@mydomain.com)  AND  -to:(*@mydomain.com)  AND -cc:(*@mydomain.com)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate different emails and use `-` (minus) to negate, like this in "to:" text box, like this (literally):

`@domain.tld -user@domain.tld`

This would make possible labelling or processing a catch-all, so it would match every email for `@domain.tld` which is NOT (-) for `user@domain.tld`. Thanks to @Marcos for helping me find the answer.