# Gmail labeling forwarded emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, email-forwarding

I have 2 emails 1 for school (= outlook) and 1 personal(=gmail)

I forward my outlook emails to my personal gmail.

The forwarded emails I receive in my gmail should get a label called **school**
But I can't seem to filter it

Example Peter sends an email to my outlook school mail. That mail automatically being forwarded to my personal gmail with this heading:

```
from:            <peter@someDomain> via outlook.studentMail.com
to:              myName@outlook.studentMail.com
mailed-by:       outlook.studentMail.com
```

I tried this [topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31536/how-to-filter-emails-forwarded-to-gmail-alias) and few basic filters but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a filter with this

> to:(myName@outlook.studentMail.com)

in the "Has the words" field. Note that this is different from putting `myName@outlook.studentMail.com` in the To: field.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much!