# In Gmail, how can I know when I started to automatically forward emails to a colleague?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail desktop, you can automatically forward emails to another email address, in "settings". How can I know when I set this forwarding up? I tried getting the first forwarded email by filtering emails using "to:collegue@company.com" and "deliveredto:collegue@company.com" in the "contains the word" field like described in [How to Filter Emails Forwarded to Gmail Alias?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31536/how-to-filter-emails-forwarded-to-gmail-alias), but I got 0 result.