# How to create a filter in Gmail to identify messages forwarded from Zimbra?

Tags: gmail-filters, zimbra

**EDIT:**  You cand find additional information in [Is it possible to create a Gmail filter that works on headers other than From, To, Subject?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/is-it-possible-to-create-a-gmail-filter-that-works-on-headers-other-than-from-t)

I have two email accounts, one is my main Gmail account which I check regularly (for simplicity I name it *mygmail@gmail.com*), and the other one is from university mail service where I currently study (and I name it *myunimail@mail.uni.com*).

As the disk quota of university mail server is too low and there are lots of daily announcements from university staff which contain huge attachments, after about 5-7 days all disk quota is used and afterwards no emails will be delivered to my inbox.

So I created a filter in the university mail service (which uses Zimbra) to forward all received messages to email alias *mygmail+**UNIFWD**@gmail.com* and then delete the message.

**Now the main problem is:** I want to create a filter in Gmail to mark these forwarded messages with a custom label, but the information included in message header, specially **FROM** and **TO** fields, is not enough to distinguish these messages from other ones (as shown below)

[image: Mail information]

As you can see, *there is no sign of alias I used in the Forwarding Address* in Zimbra's filter settings.
Even I can't rely on **TO** field (which contains myunimail@mail.uni.com) because there are messages which are sent to both of my email addresses, so some mistakes will occur if I use this field.

By the way, these forwarded messages are marked by Gmail as being sent **via mail.uni.com**

Is there any way I can use this to filter messages?

Did I miss something while setting up the filter in Zimbra?

Comment: Try searching/filtering on `deliveredto:mygmail+UNIFWD@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `deliveredto:` search keyword.

> Search for messages within a particular email address in the Delivered-To line of the message header
>
> Example: deliveredto:username@gmail.com
>   Meaning: Any message with username@gmail.com in the Delivered-To: field of the message header (which can help you find messages forwarded from another account or ones sent to an alias).

([Google support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190))

So, searching for (or using a filter with) `deliveredto:mygmail+UNIFWD@gmail.com` should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks, `deliveredto` keyword works fine with all Gmail and Google Admin Domains, but not working if other email account is hotmail or a simple admin by cpanel account, is that field called different in other email providers?