# Create a Gmail filter for Calendar Notifications

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, gmail-filters

I'd like to create a Gmail filter to filter all of my Google Calendar notifications into a separate folder.

Google Calendar notifications have headers that look like the following:

```
Reply-To: Helen Seu <h...@g...com>
Sender: Google Calendar <calendar-notification@google.com>
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Date: Thu, 01 May 2014 05:25:28 +0000
Subject: Updated Invitation: Mobile design review @
 Fri May 9, 2014 3pm - 4pm
From: Helen Seu <h..@g...com>
To: "Mike Burton" <m...@g...com>,
```

In particular, the email Reply-To is the user who created the meeting, and the Sender is `calendar-notification@google.com`.

For some reason, Gmail does not seem to allow you to filter on the `Sender` field of an email. Is there another clever way to filter Google Calendar notifications to a separate folder?

Comment: take à look here maybe it can helps : https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/gmail/common-filters/#!/

Comment: Why is it not possible to filter for any mail header. For example "Sender: calendar-notification@google.com" and " Auto-Submitted: auto-generated". All answers to this question are very likely to match to messages which they should not match.

Answer (score 83):

Ever since the recent Google Calendar changes, I've found this updated filter to work best.

**As a search:**

`subject:("invitation" OR "accepted" OR "rejected" OR "updated" OR "canceled event" OR "declined" OR "proposed") when where calendar who organizer`

**As a filter:**

```
From: 
To: 
Subject:          "invitation" OR "accepted"
                  OR "rejected" OR "updated" OR "canceled event" 
                  OR "declined" OR "proposed"
Has the words:    when where calendar who organizer
Doesn't have:
```

Comment: ...adding a `AND has:attachment` help me to stay clear of personal email conversations, that carried from an automated calendar emails... (as long as they don't happen to tack on attachments, too)

Comment: This is great. I would suggest adding `-Re` to the "Has the words" section so you don't miss responses to event messages

Comment: Spelling fixed.

Answer (score 47):

For those looking to filter all calendar proposals (no updates)

```
from:(-me) {filename:vcs filename:ics} has:attachment
```

Comment: how do you add this filter? Where do you put the filename in the filter screen?

Comment: Google's documentation.
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308760?hl=en

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps the simplest way is

```
Has the words: "google.com/calendar"
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: @serenesat Yes, the actual  message source contains multiple references to `https://www.google.com/calendar/*` which may change in future but I expect that those links won't go away.

Comment: this is simpler than all the other kludges here (but still does not catch `[Update]`

Answer (score 12):

All calendar invites have a file attached:

```
filename:invite.ics
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want the filter to apply to all Google Calendar emails, you can use the "Has words" field of the filter and use

```
*.ics AND has:attachment AND ("Invitation:" OR "Accepted" OR "Declined")
```

I use this and it works well.

Comment: @Adach1979: I incorporated your comment into your answer. Comments are meant to be temporary and can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following filters:

1. Matches daily agenda emails and notifications about the upcoming events: `from:(calendar-notification@google.com)`
2. Matches new events, invitations, accepted, declined, updated invitations, cancelled events: `"Invitation from Google Calendar"` (double quotes are important).

Answer (score 1):

Please try to filter the following... It would show all the active invitations.

```
invite.ics has:attachment
```

Answer (score 1):

This filters all calendar related mails, nothing else is required.

```
Has the words: filename:invite.ics
```

Also, no language specifics terms are required here.

Answer (score 0):

Now, to answer the *into a separate folder* part:

GMail doesn't use folders; instead, it allows you to tag messages with labels.  To stop messages from being shown in the *Inbox* and make them appear as a separate collection with a name of your own choosing (which is what folders are for in other systems), create a label with that name, assign the label to those messages, and remove them from the Inbox.

[You can create a filter rule to do this automatically when messages come in.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/EMVkdKChP2I)

Answer (score 0):

Elegantly:

**Includes the words:** `filename:.ics`

Bonus: **Excludes the words:** `first name of ceo, first name of cto` etc so you don't miss the important ones

Answer (score -1):

Here's an idea:

Leave all other fields blank except *Has the words*, enter: *View on Google Calendar*.