# How do I create a Gmail filter for external calendar notifications (e.g., from Outlook)?

Tags: gmail-filters, calendar

My question is similar to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60188/create-a-gmail-filter-for-calendar-notifications), but I would like to filter calendar notifications that came from applications *other than* Google Calendar. I have been successfully filtering Google Calendar notifications using the filter `Has the words: *.ics ("Invitation:" OR "Accepted" OR "Declined")`, but have not found a way to filter calendar notifications from Outlook users.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of an email invitation sent from MS Outlook. Unfortunately, since it's a work account, I can't include the message source. The only reference the source contains to "calendar" is `Content-Type: text/calendar;`. It appears as though Gmail is automatically parsing some information and creating the calendar box shown above the text of the email.

[image: Calendar invite email from MS Outlook]

Comment: I am currently testing out `Has the words: +who +when +where +organizer +time` and it seems to be capturing most - maybe all - of what I need. I'll continue testing this filter.

Comment: You need to find some unique part of the text to filter on. Maybe if you offered up a sample message someone could offer some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how I missed this previously, but the following filter seems to correctly catch all Microsoft Outlook calendar invites, updates, etc.

Has the words: `filename:ics`