# Gmail filtering from forwarded accounts?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I currently have a few accounts forwarding into Gmail, and I have Gmail set up to send through those accounts as well - your standard inbox consolidation via Google.

For ages now, I've been labeling the messages that use those accounts through filters like:

```
Has the words:
from:{me@work.edu}|to:{me@work.edu}
```

This is great, as anything I send or receive with that account gets tagged appropriately.

The issue I'm trying to solve arises when I get a message that's been sent to a list that my `me@work.edu` address is on or when I'm BCC'ed to the `me@work.edu` address - the filter doesn't pick up these use cases. I [read here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/is-it-possible-to-create-a-gmail-filter-that-works-on-headers-other-than-from-t) that the `delivered-to` option is what I want, but upon exploring that just now, I found that no matter what address the message was sent to, across the board, I have:

```
Delivered-To: me@gmail.com
```

Is that how `delivered-to` is supposed to work?

Am I doing something wrong, or just understanding something wrong?

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work for all cases?

As a kludgey solution, I currently have something like:

```
Has the words:
from:{me@work.edu}|to:{me@work.edu list1@work.edu list2@work.edu etc}
```

But that doesn't catch the BCCs, and needs to be modified over time. I also just read about setting other accounts to forward to `me+something@gmail.com`, and then filtering based on that instead, though that strikes me as equally kludgey. I imagine something more elegant has to exist.

Comment: No, I don't think you've missed anything. That's part of the trouble with bcc. `delivered-to:` should help, but even then it falls down. Don't knock `me+something@gmail.com`. I use it all the time; it's quite helpful.