# Create filter on Gmail for BCC to myself

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I run a startup and we send quite a lot of emails. I've started to BCC these emails that my software sends to myself as an alias. For example:

`layke@example.com` might be my main email and I'm now sending them to

`layke+blind@example.com` as a bcc to field, (in addition to the clients email as the main "to" field).

The problem is that I can't seem to create a filter for these emails in my Inbox. I want to archive them immediately, but it doesn't appear as though there is a way to do this.

If I search for emails, I can't see them. I guess this is because Gmail doesn't store the BCC field (even if it's sent to you).

[image]

Headers of email:

[image: screenshot]

I think my only option is to create a fully fledged inbox JUST for these BCC's as I can't find any way to identify and label them.

Comment: Closely related: [Is it possible to create a Gmail filter that works on headers other than From, To, Subject?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5719/354)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to filter on the `delivered-to` header.

Fortunately, Gmail allows you to do that.

Use the [advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190/) flag in the "has the words" field for your filter. For example:

```
 deliveredto:layke+blind@example.com
```

You can probably even shorten it to

```
deliveredto:blind
```

but you may get too many false positives.

I have a few similar filters for just this purpose.

Comment: This works perfectly. Just tested, and it filtered with only the blind emails. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of bcc is that the recipients *don't see* who is on bcc. That includes all receivers, even the ones on bcc. So when the email to yourself arrives, you are *not* on bcc anymore, as it is not shown to anyone.

You can use cc: for the effect you want, and the receiver mailbox will know that you are on cc: and can handle rules to it. But then everyone else will see it too.

Comment: I'm afraid you're mistaken here. It _is_ possible to filter messages that you received by being in the bcc address. You just need to use the `delivered-to:` heading.

Comment: @Al E. - that would also catch the ones where you are on to: and cc:, wouldn't it? So basically all your mails.

Comment: Asker is using "plus addressing" to be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: Yep, I'm using a layke+this.is.custom@example. @Al E is correct, his solution works great.